# 8 Queens puzzle algorithm not working properly

Tags: java, recursion, backtracking, n-queens

I am experiencing some issues with the implementation of the 8 Queens Problem via Backtracking. My code is not throwing any errors anymore but somehow the solution found is wrong. Here is my code:

```
public class Queens {

public int[] field = new int[8];

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Queens();
}

public Queens() {
    initField();
    if (backtrack(0)) {
        out();
    }
}

boolean backtrack(int i) {
    while (i < 8) {
        if (danger(i)) {
            field[i] += 1;
            if (field[i] < 8) {
                return backtrack(i);
            } else {
                field[i] = 0;
                field[i - 1] += 1;
                return backtrack(i - 1);
            }
        } else {
            if (field[i] < 8) {
                if (i == 7) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return backtrack(i + 1);
                }
            } else {
                field[i] = 0;
                field[i - 1] += 1;
                return backtrack(i - 1);
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public void initField() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        field[i] = 0;
    }
}

public boolean danger(int i) {
    for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        if (field[i] == field[j]) {
            return true;
        }
        if (Math.abs(field[i] - i) == Math.abs(field[j] - j)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public void out() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        System.out
                .println("Line: " + (i + 1) + ", Field: " + (field[i] + 1));
    }
}
}
```

And this is the output:

```
Line: 1, Field: 4
Line: 2, Field: 8
Line: 3, Field: 7
Line: 4, Field: 5
Line: 5, Field: 3
Line: 6, Field: 6
Line: 7, Field: 2
Line: 8, Field: 1
```

The position of queen 2 and 3 as well as the position of queen 7 and 8 is illegal. I have searched my code for mistakes but I'm afraid I don't find any.

/e: Changed my danger method to this:

```
public boolean danger(int i) {
    for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        if (field[i] == field[j]) {
            return true;
        }
        if (Math.abs(field[i] - i) == Math.abs(field[j] - j)) {
            return true;
        }
        if(Math.abs(field[i] + i) == Math.abs(field[j] + j)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

The question is answered, I still need to fix some bugs tho ._.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive. You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, by tracing the progress of your program, and comparing it to what you expect to happen. As soon as the two diverge, then you've found your problem. (And then if necessary, you should construct a [minimal test-case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).)

Comment: What is field? Shouldn't there be an x and a y position for the Queen?

Comment: I use that array to notate the positions of the 8 queens. The indices represent the lines and the value represents the x value

Comment: So line 1 represents x=1 and field represents y=4?

Comment: i think heuristics would be a smarter choice. Wikipedia: n queens

Answer (score 0):

in danger method

```
(Math.abs(field[i] - i) == Math.abs(field[j] - j))
```

should be

```
(Math.abs(field[i] - j) == Math.abs(field[j] - i))
```